# TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined` when trying to execute this code (all variables, including modules are defined in other parts of the code):

```
if (messageText) {
            var senderID_first_name = f_User.UserQ(senderID);
            sendTextMessage(senderID, String(senderID_first_name));
        }

f_User = {
    UserQ: function(id) {
        var parse_body;
        request.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'+id+'?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&access_token='+PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                parse_body = body;
            }
        });
        return parse_body.first_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You ran into a typical problem with the async behavior of JS. You returning date that you doesn't have yet. The data that you want are in the callback of the `get` method.

You could solve this in your architecture like this.

```
UserQ: function(id, callback) {
    var parse_body;
    request.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'+id+'?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&access_token='+PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            callback(parse_body.first_name);
        }
    });
}
```

and then

```
...
UserQ(2, function(name){
 console.log('Name for id 2', name);
});
...
```

You have to study about [callbacks and promises](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-promise-and-a-callback-in-Javascript) in JS. Good luck :—)

P.S: See this example: http://jsbin.com/jagisumode/edit?js,console

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this and I keep getting undefined in return (at least it's not crashing!). 

`if (messageText) {
            f_User.UserQ(senderID, function(senderID_first_name) {
                sendTextMessage(senderID, String(senderID_first_name));
            });
        }`

`

Comment: `f_User = {
    UserQ: function(id, callback) {
        request.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'+id+'?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&access_token='+PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body.first_name);
                callback(body.first_name);
            }
        });
    }
}`

Comment: The `console.log(body.first_name); ` is undefined? What return `body` then?

Comment: `senderID_first_name` is returning undefined :(

Comment: See this: http://jsbin.com/jagisumode/edit?js,console

How do you get that `senderID_first_name` is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you, not tested on my end.

```
if (messageText) {
    f_User.UserQ(senderID,true);
}
f_User = {
    UserQ: function(id,sendMessage=false) {
        request.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'+id+'?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&access_token='+PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                if(sendMessage)              
                    sendTextMessage(id, String(body.first_name));
             }
        });
    }
}
```